# Angular: use of rendered templates as interpolated strings for translation

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization

In my Angular application, I display a sentence like:

> [UserX] commented [item] from [UserY] at [PlaceZ]

[image: example]

This sentence (currently hardcoded in English) needs to **be translated** but the tricky thing is that `[UserX]`, `[UserY]`, `[item]` and `[PlaceZ]` are rendered through angular **components**, even inside `ng-container` switches.

This is because these elements are clickable and have their own avatar and are used all over the application for consistency.

It roughly looks like:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='user;context:{id: "X"}'></ng-container>
commented
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='impactedEntity'></ng-container>
of
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='user;context:{id: "Y"}'></ng-container>
at
<location id="Z"></location>

<ng-template #user let-id="id">
<!-- display "you" if same user, etc -->
...
</ng-template>

<ng-template #impactedEntity>
<ng-container [ngSwitch]='type'>
...
</ng-template>
```

My question is: what is a simple solution to translate this sentence (considering the order of placeholders can change completely from one language to another), and **inject the "rendered" elements**?

I've already looked at some common options for injecting HTML inside i18n:

- split the sentence in multiple pieces "around" placeholders. But because there are 4 elements to "inject", that makes a huge combinatorial.
- put the html code directly in the translate text and use `[innerHtml]` to have the html rendered. Not applicable because it's not "just" `<a href` but more complex logic with `ng-container`.
- use `@ViewChild()` to get the rendered HTML from each element I need to inject, and use it as simple string for interpolation. It looks like the most realistic approach, but I was wondering if there was not something simpler.

Thanks for any feedback!

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I think I found a solution that fits quite well.

After more thinking, here's what I came up with:

1. the translation value (in the translation file) is pretty standard, it looks like `"MY_KEY": "{userX} commented {entity} of {userY} at {place}"`
2. when reading the translation value I interpolate values with more explicit placeholders with special characters:

```js
const label = translateService.instant(MY_KEY, {
  userX: "|USERX|",
  userY: "|USERY|",
  entity: "|ENTITY|",
  place: "|PLACE|"
})
```

3. I split this string

```js
const elements = label.split('|')
```

4. I iterate on these elements **in the template** and replace my own placeholders with their components

```html
<ng-container *ngFor='let part of elements'>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase='USERX'>
              <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='user;context:{id: "X"}'></ng-container>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase='USERY'>
              <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='user;context:{id: "Y"}'></ng-container>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase='ENTITY'>
              <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='impactedEntity'></ng-container>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase='PLACE'>
              <location></location>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
<!-- Here simply dump the translated words -->
              {{ part }}
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

In the end, it's a little hacky (not too much), but:

- translation uses a standard format
- it's totally flexible regarding the order of words
- the template remains readable and there's no low level DOM manipulation

I'm happy!